# Drawer not covering header in react-navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation

Hi friends I am scratching my head with react-navigation from last 2 days, I tried many things(documentation doesn't seems that clear for a beginner), so right now I am facing few problem that seems little complex to me and hence I seek advice and help to proceed further.following are the cases/problem/scenario I seek help for -

1. **react-navigation does not cover the header and statusbar**, I wanted to achieve something like [gmail](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipOPoxSc70mEgFC0VerJGb2B7aEVVZzFOluQaSrI998Unx8H4Ys3FQT7HkysAnV7UQ?key=ZGlHQmp1b0ZZVmNNb01EOXZWWGp0ejBVMWw0T1hB) but I ended up with like [this](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipOUruqggUpIgenIjPNpE5fOiW0X_Ju51PEIH7Dg2au19GuqB82uLvi7MO7_LRJaHA?key=Z1B6T1NSd2hlTnRpUGJUam9NUEQweVB4RFJ0NnlR)

I used following code blocks to reach to this point

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, View, BackAndroid, StatusBar,} from 'react-native';
import {
  NavigationActions,
  addNavigationHelpers,
  StackNavigator,
  DrawerNavigator
} from 'react-navigation';


import LandingScreen from 'src/screens/landingScreen';
import Login from 'src/screens/login'
import SignUp from 'src/screens/signUp'
import ForgotPassword from 'src/screens/forgotPassword'
import Dashboard from 'src/screens/dashboard'
import UserProfile from 'src/screens/userProfile'

export const Drawer = DrawerNavigator({
  Dashboard:{
    path:'/',
    screen:Dashboard,
  },
  UserProfile:{
    path:'/'
    screen:UserProfile
  },
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Dashboard',
  contentOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
  },
  headerMode: 'screen',
});

const routesConfig = {
  Landing:{screen:LandingScreen},
  Login: { screen: Login },
  SignUp: { screen: SignUp },
  ForgotPassword: { screen: ForgotPassword },
  Drawer:{screen:Drawer}
};

export const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(routesConfig, {
  initialRouteName: 'Drawer'
});
AppRegistry.registerComponent('Riduk', () => AppNavigator);
```

2. **Other problem is how should I add 2 drawers in my app at the same screen**

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I used drawerNavigator as the parent navigator for my app, have a look on my navigator structure https://github.com/manjeets12/riduk/blob/master/src/containers/AppNavigator.js

Comment: Thanks, I had implemented a similar solution and it worked

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simplified example:

```js
const FooStackNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Foo: { 
    screen: FooScreen, 
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Foo',
    }
  },
});
const BarStackNavigator = StackNavigator({...});

const MyDrawerNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
  FooStack: { 
    screen: FooStackNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawer: () => ({
        label: 'Foo',
      })
    },
  },
  BarStack: { 
    screen: BarStackNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawer: () => ({
        label: 'Bar',
      })
    },
  }
});

const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Drawer: { screen: MyDrawerNavigator },
}, {
  headerMode: 'none',
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an [issue](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/68) for Header in DrawerNavigator.

But you can fix by using **StackNavigator inside DrawerNavigator**

```
export const Drawer = DrawerNavigator({
  Dashboard:{
    path:'/',
    screen: StackNavigator( { Screen1: {
                screen: Dashboard
            }})
  },
  UserProfile:{
    path:'/',
    screen: StackNavigator( { Screen1: {
                screen: UserProfile
            }})
  },
}});
```

Then set `headerMode: 'none'` to **root StackNavigator**

```
export const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(routesConfig, {
    headerMode: 'none'
});
```

Here, AppNavigator is root StackNavigator and routesConfig has above DrawerNavigator and other screens.

Comment: This worked, but the icon which I had added for navigation drawer goes off completely, I had added icon under the drawercomponent.

Comment: After adding headerleft to the inner stacknavigator( screen1) the icon is back.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the issue you're trying to resolve?

https://blog.callstack.io/android-drawer-statusbar-done-right-for-react-native-7e85f01fc099

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, you have to do 2 things:
 1. Put drawer control at the top of navigation stack.
 2. Set `translucent` propery of StatusBar

```
<StatusBar
                translucent
                backgroundColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24)"
                animated
            />
            { Platform.OS === 'android' && Platform.Version >= 20 ?
                <View
                    style={{
                      height: 24,
                      backgroundColor: "#512DA8",
                    }}
                />
                : null }
```

Kindly let me know if it does work.

Answer (score 0):

`DrawerNavigator` must over on `StackNavigator`, this is my way to fix this:

```
const navStack = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Main, },
  Example01: { screen: Example01, },
  Example02: { screen: Example02, },
});

const navDrawer = DrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: navStack, // Drawer over on StackNavigator
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Home',
      header: null,
    }
  },
  Example03: {
    screen: Example03,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Example03',
    }
  },
},
{
  headerMode: 'none',
  headerVisible: false,
  navigationOptions: {
    header: null
  }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Looks like you wanted to write `StackNavigator` and `DrawerNavigator` in the first sentence, not `DrawerNavigator` twice, please fix that if that's the case; also, please clarify it: there's no verb in it at all. Do you mean that `StackNavigator` should be constructed before `DrawerNavigator`?

Comment: this example, is show DrawerNavigator on all StackNavigator screen and disable all StackNavigator screen header, like Example01 and Example02